# ubuntu + add root permission for new user account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I have ubuntu version - 12.04

and this is the sudoers file

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I created new user - test_app

and I want to give the same root permissions as %admin user

please advice what the additional lines that I need to add VIA visudo ?

Answer (score 5):

First of all `admin` is a group not a user you can determine that from `%` character.

Now for your question you can add a full `sudo` permission for user `test_app` by adding this line to the file:

```
test_app    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

after that you can use `sudo` with anything from user `test-app`

But I recommend you to add your user to `sudo` group so you won't have to do any change to sudoers file:

```
usermod -a -G sudo test_app
```